# What exactly is an "Entity Type" in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What exactly does the phrase "Entity Type" mean in Entity Framework 6?

I've searched in vain for a strict definition, but it seems to refer to any entity defined as a DbSet in a class that derives from DbContext.  Is that a complete definition? Or can it mean anything else?

For example, in the code snippet below, is "MyClass" the only way an "Entity Type" can be defined?

```
 public class MyDbContext : DbContext
 {
      public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.  It's a class that has a corresponding db table.  Of course, you define MyClass somewhere else, but by putting it in the DbContext as in your example it makes the context aware of your class and how it should treat it accordingly.

Comment: It might be interesting to explain, why you are asking for an exact definition. This might improve the answer

Comment: @FlexFiend However, if MyClass has properties that reference other types, then those other types are entity types as well even though they have no explicit DbSet in the context

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I'm porting LINQ to SQL into EF 6, I keep running across the phrase "Entity Type" and want to make absolutely sure I know what it means.  I've never seen the phrase strictly defined.

Comment: As FlexFiend and I said, you can assume that everything that gets a table in the database is an entity type. Even if no DbSet exists in the context for that type

Comment: So the answer is: any class defined as a DbSet, and any virtual member of said class which refers to other database objects.

Comment: It doesn't need to be `virtual`. Also shouldn't be a *Complex Type*. Also any class used in `modelBuilder.Entity<T>()` call.

Answer (score 0):

As gleaned from the comments, an "Entity Type" is:

1. Any class defined as a Dbset inside a class derived from DbContext.
2. Any member of said class which refers to database objects.
3. Any class used in a modelBuilder.Entity call.